# Pausing code execution in chrome from within JS. Possible?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, haxe

Can I pause execution from within JS code? I am working on a simple haxe-based debug util, and I want to be able to simulate breakpoints, by calling a util method which will trigger the execution pause.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but in Chrome (and Firefox if Firebug is installed) you can use the built-in JavaScript [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statement. This causes the execution to pause, and is effectively like setting a breakpoint. For example, the following would break on every iteration of the loop allowing you to examine the value of `i` (stupidly simple example):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    debugger;
    console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: In Haxe, this can be done `untyped __js__('debugger');`  Hopefully for haxe 3 we can add a simple function, such as js.Lib.debugger();

Comment: Pretty cool.  Now if there was a keyboard shortcut that could inject the debugger statement into the console, that would be amazing.